# Calling Stored Procedure through CRUD repository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures, crud

Can anyone give example of "how to call stored Procedure through CRUD repository in Springboot?" or "any annotation required for calling stored procedure from JPA repository?"

Answer (score 0):

you can use MyBatis like

```
<insert id="addUser" parameterType="com.xxx.User" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {call insert_user(#{id,mode=OUT,jdbcType=INTEGER},#{name,mode=IN})}
</insert>
```

Answer (score 0):

Procedure example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MOVE_TO_HISTORY(IN person_id_in INT, OUT status_out BOOLEAN)
```

JPA repository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Transactional
    @Procedure(procedureName = "MOVE_TO_HISTORY")
    boolean movePersonToHistory(@Param("person_id_in") int personId);
}
```

You can find this great example [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/stored-procedure.html)